# What are the possible gotchas with reading a file that's actively being written on linux?

Tags: linux, io

I have an application that is actively writing stuff to a bunch of files (always keeping them open for writing, not opening and closing them).

What are the possible problems with opening them for reading from another application, provided that this other application properly handles any kind of malformed data?

For example, could I block the writing application by opening the file for reading? Could I crash it? Could the reading application block?

Comment: you won't block writing application. only problem I can see is you may have more data by the time you finished reading and very difficult to get actual EOF while reading.

Comment: The writing app writes relatively little data per second, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: you still may have the problem of EOF, but only lesser number of times. In linux you can even change the running applications's executable and it won't crash. and that is the beauty of the true multitasking OS. My traffic analyzer works this way the log writer writes hundreds of lines per sec, and never faced any problem reading. I keep the pointer to the location till i have read in a different file so i can continue from there next time. __Also note__: if you rename the file the writing application continues to write to the new file.